# Show Dialog on Project Level

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I am implementing check internet connection on project level, because i want to show the same dialog on all activity in Project.
I am using Broadcast receiver and i registered that on Application activity.
it is giving me my desire output in Toast but when i show dialog in Receiver class, my application crash and it is giving me null pointer exception.

Whats your opinion about it.

Comment: `Whats your opinion about it.` fix your nullpointer, all of them are resolved the same way. you haven't posted any code here so it's quite difficult to give an actual answer, but even if you did post code and your stack trace, the answer would be the same. _why_ you're getting the nullpointer is more relevant, figure out what's null and fix it

Answer (score 1):

You can change this a bit instead of listening to broadcast in the application create a BaseActivity class and make all your Activity classes extend from this Base class.
Now in BaseActivity you can start listening to the broadcast in `onStart()` and stop in `onStop()`. Here you will always have an activity context thus you can show any kind of alert including toast / dialog etc.

Comment: Will that work you think? I am not sure if that would work, its better to create a `Service` instead and write the code there.

Comment: @SagarBalyan If we host the Broadcast Receiver in Service then again he cannot directly inflate a dialog fragment he will need an activity's context so he will have to create a way to inform the same to current activity through binding with service or local broadcast which would only complicate the design.